# Communicate printer through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have to develop a web page that have a button to print the current web page. How can I achieve this through JavaScript? Or Is there any other scripting language or framework to achieve this easily?

**UPDATE**

I have to pass some data from my server or my browser memory to the printer driver so that I can use these data to print in a formatted way.

Comment: You can't use JS to print directly without the user confirming it via the browser's Print dialog. But you can open that dialog from JS.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `window.print()`. That is same as the user pressing e.g. `Ctrl + P` on windows.